# UITextField doesn't allow 3rd party keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a `scrollView` in a `viewController`'s main `view`, which contains two `textFields`, an email and a password

If I set `isSecureEntry = true` on the password field (**only**), the email can not use 3rd party keyboards (doesn't matter what `keyboardType` I set it to, either). Is this normal behaviour? If it detects a secure `textField` on a view, it disables 3rd party keyboards for all `textFields`? Because if I set `isSecureEntry = false` on the password field, both text fields can use the 3rd party keyboard.

`UITextViews` throughout the app can properly use it, also other `UITextFields` in other views.

If it matters, this bunch of system constraints break when bringing the language changer popup up:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d02966c0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x102c6d820.leading == UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6df20.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0296760 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6fc00]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x102c6d820 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0296800 'UISV-fill-equally' UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6efd0.width == UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6df20.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d02968f0 'UISV-fill-equally' UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6fc00.width == UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6df20.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d02967b0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6df20]-(9)-[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6efd0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d02968a0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6efd0]-(9)-[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6fc00]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d0295860 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIStackView:0x102c6d820.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d02968a0 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6efd0]-(9)-[UIInputSwitcherTableCellSegmentView:0x102c6fc00]   (active)>
```

Thank you!

Comment: > Is this normal behaviour?
Yes, Apple  prohibited the use 3rd party keyboards

Comment: I suppose there’s no workaround to keep one field secure, but allow other fields to use 3rd party keyboard?

Comment: Other fields can use 3rd if its not secure of course

Comment: But that’s the issue: no non secure textFields can use 3rd party keyboard if any secure textField exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you enable the secure text entry for the textfield,system will limit the third party keyboard,it also affect the textfield before,that is the email textfield in your situation.But it only affect one textfield before the textfield which has secure text entry porperty.That mean,if your have three textfield in a view,the view hierarchy like this:

--scrollView

-textfield1(can use third party keyboard)

-textfield2(can not use third party keyboard)

-textfield3(secure text entry)(can not use third party keyboard)

You see,the top textfield will not be affect by the secure text entry porperty.
So,i have found a solution in your situation,you can insert a textfield with very small height(but not hidden,such as 0.5) between the email textfield and password textfield.Now,you can use third party keyboard in your email textfield.

Comment: That's so ... ugh. I wonder if it's on purpose (and the reasoning behind it) or a bug that went by for too long. Thank you!

Comment: "But it only affect one textfield before the textfield which has secure text entry property." - Is this documented somewhere or is it a bug? Still happens in iOS 15.